# Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY' in alter table

Tags: mysql, sql

I get an error when I import sql file in phpmyadmin. Here is an error

```
--
-- Indexes for table 'tbl_disposisi'
--
ALTER TABLE 'tbl_disposisi'
  ADD PRIMARY KEY ('disposisi_kd'),
  ADD KEY 'fk_tbl_disposisi_tbl_berita_idx' ('arsip_kd')

#1062 - Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your data contains duplicates in `disposisi_kd` (for example, at least 2 rows with the value of `2` in this column exists). You must alter or remove such values (and NULLs if exists) then create primary key.

Comment: It's clearly not a primary key when it contains duplicates. It maybe a `KEY` (in index) but don't mistake that as a primary key.

Comment: You can run a query like `SELECT disposisi_kd, COUNT(*) FROM tbl_disposisi GROUP BY disposisi_kd HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to find duplicate `disposisi_kd`

Comment: I get 25 primary key of data duplicate, so for the next step what should I do?

Comment: The next step is for you to check all those duplicates and see if you need all of them or you need just 1 of each.

Comment: Well, maybe you can do something like this `SELECT * FROM tbl_disposisi  WHERE disposisi_kd IN (*all the 25 disposisi_kd values that have duplicates*) ORDER BY disposisi_kd`. Once the result returned, you can compare (by eye) if all is needed or just 1 of each. You can also run `SELECT A.* FROM tbl_disposisi  A JOIN (SELECT disposisi_kd, COUNT(*) FROM tbl_disposisi GROUP BY disposisi_kd HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B ON A.disposisi_kd=B.disposisi_kd ORDER BY A.disposisi_kd`.

Comment: Thank you everyone I found the mistake.

Comment: Ah well, okay.. you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

It is as @Akina says, you have multiple rows with the same `disposisi_kd`

In reaction to the comment on how te show the duplicates:

```
SELECT 
    disposisi_kd , 
    COUNT(disposisi_kd ) as sameIdCount
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY disposisi_kd 
HAVING sameIdCount> 1;
```

should do the trick (don't forget to replace `table_name`)

Comment: Thank you, I've already know the duplicate data. And I dont know for the next step

Comment: @AnggitaPuspawardani *And I dont know for the next step* Either remove this rows or edit them and set unique values into this column. PS. Also check that this column does not contain NULLs.

Comment: yes change those ID's. You cannot have the same values in a PRIMARY KEY column. so either change those ID's to something unique or use a different type of INDEX.

Answer (score 0):

you can also choose another primary key or use a couple of columns as primary key if you need:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.ASP